# Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException when trying to upload file to AWS

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I'm trying to create an s3 bucket and then upload a file to it. However, when I run the code I get this ugly error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Found 1 error while
> validating the input provided for the PutObject operation: [Body] must
> be an fopen resource, a GuzzleHttp\Stream\StreamInterface object, or
> something that can be cast to a string. Found bool(false) in
> /Users/ddripz/Downloads/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Api/Validator.php:65

Stack trace:

```
#0 /Users/ddripz/Downloads/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Middleware.php(78): Aws\Api\Validator->validate('PutObject', Object(Aws\Api\StructureShape), Array) 
#1 /Users/ddripz/Downloads/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/S3/S3Client.php(541): Aws\Middleware::Aws\{closure}(Object(Aws\Command), NULL) 
#2 /Users/ddripz/Downloads/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/S3/S3Client.php(564): Aws\S3\S3Client::Aws\S3\{closure}(Object(Aws\Command), NULL) 
#3 /Users/ddripz/Downloads/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/S3/S3Client.php(498): Aws\S3\S3Client::Aws\S3\{closure}(Object(Aws\Command), NULL) 
#4 /Users/ddripz/Downloads/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/S3/S3Client.php(517) in /Users/ddripz/Downloads/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Api/Validator.php on line 65
```

Here is my PHP code:

```php
<?php
// Require the Composer autoloader.
require '/Users/ddripz/Downloads/vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;

// Instantiate an Amazon S3 client.
$s3 = new S3Client([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region'  => 'us-west-2',
    'credentials' => [
      'key' => 'API KEY',
      'secret' => 'SECRET KEY'
    ]
]);

$bucketname = 'we-sign-file-manager';
$file_path = '/Users/DennisWarfield/Desktop/wesign/uploads/5f31fc30410c17.68431957.jpg';
$key = basename($file_path);

try {
    $s3->putObject([
        'Bucket' => '',
        'Key'    => 'my-object',
        'Body'   => fopen('/path/to/file', 'r'),
        'ACL'    => 'public-read',
    ]);
} catch (Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception $e) {
    echo "There was an error uploading the file.\n";
}

 ?>
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Also, I'm confused as to why the error is occurring on line `65` when the max number of lines in my php file is 32.

Is my `autoload.php` path incorrect because the file is in downloads?

Comment: Read the error message: `Found bool(false)`.  In your call to `putObject`, you define Body as `fopen(...)`.  But `fopen` can return false if the open failed.  I would look at this first, make your code fail proof in case the fopen fails.  he, why put `'/path/to/file'` ?  Why not `$file_path` ?  And `'Bucket'` is blank?  Why not $bucketname?  Looks like an incomplete  copy-paste...

Comment: fopen()  only works if you enable for EC instance with php access .  if you access s3 from an other hosting provider or from localhost you have to use putObject  and getObject   instead of fopen()

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
'Body'   => fopen('/path/to/file', 'r'),
```

to

```
'Body'   => fopen($file_path, 'r'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your config/filesystems.php  and make sure in s3 all the data and thier path is correct if not then correct them.